# UILabel font size "System 0.0" like UITableViewCell subtitle

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, uilabel

Can I set the font size of any `UILabel` in Interface Builder  to `0.0`?

When I create a new `UITableViewController` in Interface Builder in Xcode and set the prototype cell style to `Subtitle`, the `UILabel` labeled 'Title' has font size `System 0.0`. Also, the size text field is blank with a placeholder `Point Size`. If you click 'Done', the font remains `System 0.0`.

[image: Font System 0.0 in Xcode interface builder]

I have tried setting the font size of a different `UILabel` to values such as `0`, `0.0`, and I've tried leaving the field blank and clicking 'Done', but in every case the font size is set to `1.0`.

Comment: What would be the point of a zero-size font?

Comment: The `UILabel` in a subtitle-style `UITableViewCell` has font size `0.0`, but you can see that it is visible, and it appears to *actually* have size nearly `18.0`. I want to make a custom `UITableViewCell` as similar to subtitle style as possible.

Comment: "I want to make a custom UITableViewCell as similar to subtitle style as possible" Then use the corresponding dynamic font.

Answer (score 0):

The size 18 corresponds to the standard system size for labels. For your custom cell, you should use the Text Styles section of the Font pop-up to set the dynamic font-and-size of your label:

[image]

You may have to experiment in order to decide what text style suits best.